# amcharts editor data labels

Tags: editor, amcharts

Im using standart Editor of Amcharts
I have a simple questions - how do I trigger appearance of the data labels on a chart? I can't find the opportunity to show it by default.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

Your answers very valuable, indeed. So many answers, I have never seen that sort of acitivity in my life.

Meanwhile, for all who stacked, the question is - simply add [[value]] to the Label text... and whoala - you have your data labels withtin the chart. Enjoy.

If you want to something right - do it yourself. In this case - teach yourself.